# javascript удалить из строки символи "https://"

Tags: javascript

Необходимо удалить из строки символы `https://`

```
sid = sid1.replace(/https:///g, '');
```

- не работает)

Comment: дак `http://` или `//`? и пример входной строки в студию

Comment: зачем вам вообще тут регулярные выражения, если строка - константа?

Comment: надо именно убрать “https://”

Comment: Экранируйте слеши и будет работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте мой вариант для одной строки:

```js
var sid1 = 'https://www.google.com'; 
var sid = sid1.replace('https://', ''); 
console.info(sid);
```

Если массив строк:

```js
var sid1 = 'https://www.google.com https://ya.ru';
sid1.split(' https://').forEach(function(item) {
console.info(item);
});
```

Comment: А если в строке две ссылки?

Comment: покажите пример

Comment: Какой пример? `var sid1 = 'https://www.google.com https://ya.ru';`

Comment: @Visman, пожалуйста, с массивом

Comment: @PauloBerezini, Вы что-то перемудрили :)

Comment: Я не про то: использовать деление по пробелу и удаление каждой части...

Comment: @Skyrocker поправил, спасибо сам не подумал

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'https://site.com';

console.info(str.replace('https://', '')); // site.com
```

Или так:

```js
let str = 'https://site.com and https://google.com';

console.info(str.replace(/https:\/\//ig, '')); // site.com and google.com
```